# What does "滿腦門子的黑線" mean?

Tags: translation

> 腦門子

would be forehead.

> 黑線

is black lines.

Does it mean something like "veins popping on his forehead"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not popping veins, but cold sweat for frustration or helplessness, usually as a response to something completely out of the line or out of the context.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga_iconography):

> Parallel vertical lines with dark shading over the head or under the eye may represent mortification, fatigue, or horror. If the lines are wavy, it may represent disgust. A far cuter way to represent frustration/mortification is (mainly for female/ young female characters) they tend to puff out their cheeks while their line is delivered in a gruff voice, an elongated 3 showing puffed lips to show that puffed look more.

[image]

Popping vein is visualized and then character-ized as '头上一个大大的**井**字'.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is '满脸黑线', but I think it just means 'scowling' because someone said/did something dumb.

Too much praying can get you a black mark:http://www.gowister.com/islam-answer-1488.html

and here are some astrological aspects: http://askastrologer.com/articles/Forehead-reading.html

Answer (score 0):

It describes a situation where you don't know how to respond. Include but not limited to embarrassment and unexpected dramatic change.

Answer (score 0):

Its to signal disbelief or even disgust at something that just happened